# xml validation without xsd

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

is it possible to validate your xml file without an xsd? this xml file is an object instance serialized from a model. So when i deserialize this is it possible to validate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate you need a set of rules, against which you validate. It can be XSD or DTD or even you own rules, but you need some.

It is often useful to derive some XSD and validate documents with common tools.